# Read text into an array

Tags: java

Good day, 
I need assistance in storing a text file into an array. I am new to java but I am having a hard time with saving the items in the array. Below is what I have done so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args )
{
Scanner in = null;
try {
in = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    }
 catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get the number of cases
    int numCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

   // Call search on each iteration through the loop
    for(int i = 0; i < numCases; i++){
       int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        String[] tower_height = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                int num_tower[] = new int[n];
                in.nextInt();
            }

                for (int i = 0; i > j; i++){
                    int tower_height[] = new int[j];

                 int t_height =interger.parseInt( tower_height[]);

                     }

            }
            }

           int numTower []  = new int [n];

       }

      String []height = in.nextLine().split(" ");
      tower [] = new int [numTower];


      int height[] = new int [num_tower]

      int[n] num_towers; 

    }

    for (i = 0; )
       for (int i =0; i < n; i++)
       tower_height [i] = in.nextInt();


      int[]tower_height = new int[n];

        for (int j =0; j < num_towers; j++){
        ;
        hight[i] = in.nextInt();

         for (int k = 0; k < height; k++){
             int span[] = new int [num_tower];
              span[k-1] = height[];
              **/
         }

   }

    }         

}
```

**my text file contents**

```
6
7
100 80 60 70 60 75 85
2
50 60
10
150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70 60
10
60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150
20
60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150 150 140 130 120 110 100 90 80 70
60
30
245 34 88 90 57 165 227 58 208 129 97 26 133 110 63 127 201 213 225
171 187 74 163 21 172 143 215 66 45 216
```

Comment: Essentially you need the contents of the file in `String[] tower_height`, am I right?

Comment: You want to store each line in the array or each number?

Comment: It looks like you tried several things, mixed them together, and left them all in the code.  Everything up to and including `int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());` is correct.  I suggest you delete everything after that line, and take a minute to think about what you actually want to store.  For each case, you want to create an `int[]` array *once,* not inside the loop that reads the tower height values.  And remember to actually use the value returned by `in.nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, the answer given by Hector Manuel Martinez Duran can be simplified:

```
public List<String> txtToArray(String path)
{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.lines().toArray();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream("path/of/text"));
```

Add  below dependancy to mevan

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```